# How do update to table1.column value from table2.rows count with where condition in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do update to table1.column value from table2.rows count with where condition in SQL server

Comment: do you mean a specific row or row count from table2?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Add snapshot of tables it will help to resolve your query fast

Comment: You shouldn't normally *store* that which can be *calculated*. All you do by storing some kind of count (not clear yet what) is to open up the possibility for that calculated value to become *wrong* because it's out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go. See if it gives you enough to work with.

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 AS TABLE (KeyField CHAR(1)
                         ,CountField INT
                         )
DECLARE @TABLE2 AS TABLE (KeyField CHAR(1)
                         ,OtherData NVARCHAR(MAX)
                         )

INSERT  INTO @TABLE1
        (KeyField, CountField)
VALUES  ('A', 0) 
,       ('B', 0)
,       ('C', 0)

INSERT  INTO @TABLE2
        (KeyField, OtherData)
VALUES  ('A', CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
,       ('A', CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
,       ('B', CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
,       ('B', CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
,       ('B', CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
,       ('C', CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))

;
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    KeyField
              ,         COUNT(1) AS Cnt
              FROM      @TABLE2
              GROUP BY  KeyField
             )
    UPDATE  T1
    SET     T1.CountField = T2.Cnt
    FROM    @TABLE1 T1
    JOIN    cte T2 ON T2.KeyField = T1.KeyField

SELECT * FROM @TABLE1
```

For future ref it helps if you can post some data sets and expected results.  For now though this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Also worth looking at calculated fields depending on your requirements. Does require setting up a function to retrieve the count from another table, and has quite a performance hit, but data is always correct rather than waiting for you to refresh the counts in some way.

Comment: @Suresh Did this work for you? If yes can you mark as answer or give us some more specifics to provide a better solution.